# How to view complex numpy arrays in Dataviewer in VSCode? They are shown as [object Object]

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, complex-numbers

I am working with complex arrays (numpy) in python, and I use VSCode for development. When I work with real case, it's fine. I use the "Run and Debug" in VSCode to set breakpoints and debug the code. However, when I use complex numpy arrays, the data viewer is unable to show me the values of the array. They are shown as [object Object]

Here is a test example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1+2j, 3+4j],[5+5j,7+8j]])
print(a)

print("please help me view the complex array")
```

[Please take a look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzVng.png)

The numpy arrays are being stored at complex numbers (I guess there's no problem with that), as we can see on the left hand side "variables" section. However, when I try to view in the data Viewer, it doesn't print properly.

Being able to look into the values of the complex numpy arrays will really help with debugging the actual bigger codes that I am working on.

I have seen that this was a bug in VSCode but the bug was closed. Links for ref:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4288

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1138

I have through the above thread and some other threads which are stated as dupes. But I can't find a solution and I am kind of stuck. Please help me out with this! (steps if possible)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The [second link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1138) you quoted indicates that this is a problem that developers are currently piling up, and there is no solution yet